# Check for Windows Update on Windows 10 (technical preview)

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-preview

I'am not able to check for Updates on Windows 10 Techpreview. Everytime I try I get error: **80072EFD** I try some workarounds but nothing works.

- Update works on Windows defender
- Check Date and Time
- Check internet connection
- disable Firewall

Without update service I'am not able to install Features like (.Net 3.5) anybody knows to solve this issue. It is a temporary problem on Windows update Servers?

[image]

Comment: .NET 3.5 is added through Add/Remove not Windows Update.  Most of the time when one encounters this error it means the installation is corrupt.

Comment: Having the same problem on some Surface 3s today (Win 8 Pro) too. Some are fresh out of the box. Some have gone through OS reloads for good measure to troubleshoot. Problem exists on multiple devices, using different networks. Tried Windows Update troubleshooter & Internet Connection troubleshooter. No dice.

Comment: Note: Not sure if the OP has this, but my systems also aren't connecting to the Windows Store. All other Internet services seem to be fine.

Comment: It's not just you - See comments at http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/update.microsoft.com.html

Comment: @ramhound Yes it is On add/Remove but add/remove Works over Windows Update. If Windows Update not Works, add/remove also not work

Comment: 80072EFD = Internet connection issue: ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT     wininet.h

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes I know it is a Internet issue but the Internetconnection works. Updates on defender works for example and all other traffic too. Only the Update won't works

Answer (score 4):

Error code 80072EFD basically means there is some kind of connectivity issue between your machine and Windows Update. The error code existed in previous versions of Windows (7 and 8 at least) and the method to diagnose the fault is the same.

Ensure you're not using a firewall that is blocking connections to the following addresses:

- http://*.update.microsoft.com
- https://*.update.microsoft.com
- http://download.windowsupdate.com

Alternatively, ensure that the Windows Update service can make outgoing connections on ports 80 and 443.

The default Windows firewall should already allow connections to these addresses but it's worth checking anyway.

Also ensure that the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) is running as this is required for Windows Update to function correctly.

Failing that, here are some Microsoft resources that may help:

- [Temporary connection-related errors may occur when you use Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941)
- [How do I reset Windows Update components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)
- [Windows Update error 80072EFD](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-update-error-80072efd#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: It was a temporary Issue of the tech-preview. A few days later the update works.